# How to synchronize data between two systems?

Tags: .net, web-services, architecture, azureservicebus

I have two applications:

1. An ASP.NET MVC e-commerce website
2. A VB6 app manages the products, warehouses, customers, vendors, orders and invoicing. It is used by the physical stores.

Right now, these two are very strongly coupled.

Operations that use the database:

- There is a task that runs periodically on the website and checks the VB6 app's database for any product changes (mainly price and stock). If there are any differences then the website's database is updated with the info from the VB6 app;
- There are also similar tasks for synchronizing the order status and the available gift card vouchers.

Operations that use VB6 objects from .NET:

- When an order is placed on the website, it is also saved in the VB6 app.
- When a product is updated by a website admin (name, description, parent category etc), it is also updated in the VB6 app.
- When a customer updates his personal information, this is also saved in the VB6 app.
- When a customer registers on the website, the website asks the VB6 app if the customer has a loyalty card and gets his reward points.

I started to use Web API for the recently developed reward points feature. When an order is invoiced in the VB6 app, then the customer gains/loses reward points and these are sent to the website through Web API.

There are also other operations that need to be synchronized and aren't at the moment:

- order changes (add/remove products, discounts, shipping cost, product quantity change, etc)
- setting changes (VAT value, reward points value, discount values, etc)

The question is: what would be a better way to synchronize data between these applications, in a more loosely coupled way?
What would be the advantages/disadvantages of REST Services vs Service Bus?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are heading down a good path with your WebAPI.  Extracting your persistence and domain layers from both applications, pushing them down into centralized WebAPI calls means that you can change either app independently and they will always be in sync from a data standpoint.

Adding a service bus on top of your REST API would give you more decoupling, and would allow lots of other producer/consumer patterns to interject themselves.  It's really quite separate from the problem you are trying to solve though, just adding the WebAPI layer for your data persistence will make you life much better.

Comment: I was thinking I need a Service Bus, in order to still receive the data even if one of the applications is down for some time. I wouldn't like to implement a queue in both the applications, to make sure the data is sent properly. A Service Bus would do that for me. Am I right?

Comment: Why would it matter, the point is, both applications are reading and writing to the webAPI.   If one is down, they just don't write any new data.

Comment: The Web API is part of the website, so when the website is down for whatever reason, the VB6 app can't send data. It now checks for the response, and in the case of data export failure, it retries to send it until it succeeds. That's why I was thinking a queueing system would be better.

Comment: Extracting the persistence and domain layers from both applications would be a lot of work, too much work. The applications also do different things, so I don't think their data layers should be merged. It's true, there's also a lot of duplicated data (customers, orders), but I don't know if what you propose is the way to go. Especially because I am thinking that, eventually we won't need the VB6 application anymore. Does what I'm saying make sense?